# Different Formats between java8 and java12

Tags: java, locale, decimalformat

With Java8 the following code worked fine. Now i want to upgrade to java12 i've got the problem, that this will not work.

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double d = new Double(123456.8912);
    Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("de").setRegion("AT").build();

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);
    decimalFormat.applyLocalizedPattern("#.##0,00");

    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d.doubleValue()));
    // Excpected is 123.456,89
    // Output is 123456,89.
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, odd one. My guess is that https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8202537 (introduced in 11) may be to blame, but no idea why.

Comment: This problem seems to be introduced within Java9 -> [http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not a java one. Seems to be a bug in CLDR. Austria differ from Germany, but should not.

(http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252) Java used data from CLDR.

With the parameter **-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,SPI** set it will act like java8.

I will open a ticket at CLDR for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a defect on the java end but the problem seems to be the Locale object. In java 8 , when you retrieve the GroupingSeparator (like decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()) you will get a "." character. But in Java 12 the returned value is "á" which is unicode \u00E0. I tried changing the pattern to be "#\u00E0##0,00" but that didnt work. Then i changed the locale builder to use the UN M.49 3-digit code for Austria (which is 040. Complete list can be found here: https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/) . That solved the problem. Below is the code i used

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double d = new Double(123456.8912);
    Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("de").setRegion("040").build();

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator());
    System.out.println( decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator());
    System.out.println((int) decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator());
    decimalFormat.applyLocalizedPattern("#.##0,00");

    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d.doubleValue()));
    // Excpected is 123.456,89
    // Output is 123456,89.
}
```

Let me know if this atleast solves the problem , if not reveal what the problem is.
Also found that the Locale specific digits and grouping separator is provided by the jre, so it might just be the underlying provider having a problem

Comment: It happens with Oracle JRE/JDK and OpenJRE/JDK.

Comment: @Philipp Schneider, can you try running with   -Djava.locale.providers=JRE argument and see what happens?

Comment: With this parameter it works. Seems to be a bug at CLDR.

Comment: @PhilippSchneider great that you could get to the root of the problem